# Using selenium webdriver, how to click on multiple random links in webpage one after another continuously to detect broken links?

Tags: python, random, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I'm trying to write a test script that would essentially test all visible links randomly rather than explicitly specifying them, in a webpage upon login. Is this possible in Selenium IDE/Webdriver, and if so how can I do this?

```
links = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
list = links[randint(0, len(links)-1)]
```

The above will fetch all links in the first page but how do I go about testing all or as many links possible without manually adding the above code for each link/page? I suppose what I'm trying to do is *find broken links that would result in 500/404s*. Any productive way of doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you can't get the status code legitimately from selenium. You could use selenium to crawl for urls, and other library like [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to check link's status like this (or use solution with title check proposed by @MrTi):

```
import requests

def find_broken_links(root, driver):
    visited = set()
    broken = set()
    # Use queue for BFS, list / stack for DFS.
    elements = [root]
    session = requests.session()

    while len(elements):
        el = elements.pop()
        if el in visited:
            continue

        visited.add(el)

        resp = session.get(el)
        if resp.status_code in [500, 404]:
            broken.add(el)
            continue

        driver.get(el)
        links = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
        for link in links:
            elements.append(link.get_attribute('href'))

    return broken
```

Comment: There is one valid url after hitting causes a 401 which would only be caused if there was a session time out or logout. I added a working condition to prevent both cases from happening but it still gives a 401. Any advice on dealing with this? thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the url should be allowed to be visited by a regular user? Maybe you're hitting a logout url in the meantime that logs you out.

Comment: I created a list of urls that won't be hit; that list included logout and reproduced the same result. That particular url does not contain any ID so anyone logged in to the app can access it.

Comment: It is hard to tell what's the cause without knowledge of the url and the actual code.

Comment: That's true. What could be an error possibility though? There's just one particular URL `.../my_user/setting/edit/` that when called by selenium webdriver returns a 401 but if I open the same URL in the web browser it returns 200 giving proper html details. I have checked the session IDs as well. The only way I would receive the 401 would be if I was logged out and if I check the previously visited URL in the list, it wasn't a logout.

Comment: It could be that an issue of the user-agent string, some javascript-generated tokens that are passed when entering the settings page (csrf and alike) that cause 401 when missing or invalid. You could try [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) firefox add-on to see what's sent over the wire in your browser and set selenium/requests to mimic those requests.

Comment: I was looking at the 'set-cookie' parameter of the cookies object. It shows a XSRF token and a session ID for all the URLs being tested. In the case of the problematic URL it only contains the session ID which is different from the rest but no XSRF token. Is that any help?

Comment: Have you tried to exactly replay the requests from your browser using requests/selenium on the erroring URL?

Comment: I did try that and reproduced it. It must be something with the code I'm guessing; probably some wrapper or something

Comment: The only way I see it could return 401 is from `driver.get(el)` because `requests.session` and `driver` don't share a cookie jar. You could copy over the cookies from [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies) (use on the `session` object) to [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/navigating.html#cookies). Or directly from each `session.get` response.

Comment: I am not sure how that's done; Do you mean I should have a `cks = driver.get_cookies(el)` which I then need to send in `requests.get(el, cookies = cks)`?

Comment: I've rather meant `for k,v in session.cookies.iteritems(): driver.add_cookie({k: v})`. This way you'd copy over the requests cookie to selenium driver. You have to do it right before `driver.get()`.

Comment: Thanks; I tried that but after logging into the app it immediately collapses the window.

Comment: What you mean by collapses the window? You could also work it out the other way - before searching for broken urls, login using selenium and copy-over cookies from selenium to requests. This would make both clients to be authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

When testing for a bad page, I usually test for the title/url.
If you are testing a self-contained site, then you should find/create a link that is bad, and see what is unique in the title/URL, and then do something like:

```
assert(!driver.getTitle().contains("500 Error"));
```

If you don't know what the title/url will look like, you can check if the title contains "500"/"404"/"Error"/"Page not found" or if the page source contains those as well.

This will probably lead to a bunch of bad pages that aren't really bad (especially if you check for the page source), and will require you to go through each of them, and verify that they really are bad